# php get the post data when using pagination script

Tags: php, post, pagination

I have a page called mainPage.php that contain a pagination script which displays a list of pages.

```
 [1][2][3][4][5]
```

the pagination works fine but when I go to the next page the post data disappear.

```
for($i=1;$i<=$totalPage;$i++)
{
if($page==$i)
{
echo ' <input  type="button" value="'.$i.'"> ';
}
else
{
echo '<a href="mainPage.php='.$i.'"> <input type="button" value="'.$i.'"> </a>';
}}
```

is there any way to get the post data to the next page number after clicking this link:

```
 <a href="mainPage.php='.$i.'">
```

without the form.

Comment: What post data do you want to transfer to the next page? You could use the `anchor` to trigger a `on('submit')` function from jQuery.

Comment: post data like this $date = $_POST['date']; although the whole script is inside the form but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. When a form is submitted (with `method=post`) to the server, that's *one* POST request. If you want to make another POST request, you need to make another POST request. If you click a link, that's not a POST request.

I'm assuming your scenario is something like a search form, which is submitted via POST and which returns several pages of results. In this case, POST is misused anyway. An HTTP POST request should be used for altering data on the server, like registering a new user or deleting a record. Just a search form is not data alteration, it's just data retrieval. As such, your form should be `method=get`. That will result in a URL with the form values as query parameters:

```
mainPage.php?search=foobar
```

You can then trivially create pagination URLs from that:

```
printf('<a href="mainPage.php?%s">...', http_build_query(array('page' => $i) + $ _GET));
```

Which will result in:

```
mainPage.php?search=foobar&page=2
```

This way all your requests are self contained GET queries.

Comment: is there not any way to use post method?

Comment: Yes: make all your links forms and submit buttons.

Comment: I didn't get you,'make all your links forms and submit buttons' means making froms link or what? any external site you know can prefer me??

Comment: If you want to make a POST request, you need a `<form><input type="submit"></form>`. If you want to use pagination with POST, you need to make every pagination link a `<form><input type="submit"></form>` instead of an `<a href="..">`. If that's not what you're talking about, you better open a new question and explain your issue in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

try `<a href="mainPage.php?page='.$i.'">`  and get page no.  using `$_GET['page'];`

Answer (score 0):

You can do your job  by using the `GET` method instead of post.If you want to make it in post request you need to do it seperate for each one.

Comment: How to make like in post method?